# SP2013 Regional Settings URL

Tags: 2013, web-part, url, settings

I want to create a link on a sharepoint site to take the user directly to the User Regional Settings page.

The link

```
https://mysites..../_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider=....&
```

Takes the use to the Profile settings Edit screen, but if you select the Regional settings drop down, the URL does not change.

What is the value of the URL that will take the User directly there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but are you looking for this url? http://mysite...../_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx?type=user

Comment: Hi, yes I'm aware of this link, it looks good, but it does not provide the ability to allow the user to actually update this values...